# How to increase the spacing between points in a line?

Tags: winapi, gdi+, gdi

When using a standard pen (PS_DOT) and drawing a line with it, the result is as shown in the image below (magnified) [image]

There are two problems for me with that line, the first one is that, it's setting more than one pixel for a dot.  The second one is, the dots are too close together for what I'd like to do (draw a very soft line.)

I could use SetPixel but, the performance leaves a great deal to desire.

My question is: is there a reasonably fast way to draw a line where it is possible to control the number of pixels used to draw a dot and the spacing between dots ?

Essentially, a faster way of doing it than using SetPixel (which could be used to solved the problem were it not so slow.)

A snippet of code showing how it's done in C, C++ or Delphi would be great.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**  I tried IInspectable's answer of using ExtCreatePen and it is very close.  It seems that the only way to get pixels/dots instead of dashes is to use PS_ALTERNATE but, when that is used, there is no way to specify the spacing.

For reference and, in case, I am making a mistake I am not seeing, below is the test program I wrote.  What I would like is a repeating sequence of 1 dot (not a dash) followed by 2 spaces.  The output I got from the test program is shown (magnified) below: (the top line is obtained using PS_ALTERNATE, the bottom line using the array that specifies 1 dot, 2 spaces - which gives 2 dots and 2 spaces.)

[image]

test program:

```
{$APPTYPE        GUI}

{$LONGSTRINGS    OFF}
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}

program _ExtCreatePen;

uses Windows, Messages;

const
  AppName  = 'ExtCreatePen';

{$ifdef VER90} { Delphi 2.0 }
type
  ptrint  = longint;        // NativeInt  for newer versions
  ptruint = dword;          // NativeUint  "    "      "
{$endif}

{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function WndProc (Wnd : HWND; Msg : UINT; wParam, lParam : ptrint)
         : ptrint; stdcall;
const
  PenPattern   : packed array[1..4] of DWORD = (1, 2, 1, 2); { 1 dot, 2 spaces}

  PenBrush     : TLOGBRUSH = (lbStyle:BS_SOLID; lbColor:0; lbHatch:0);
  PenWidth     : DWORD     = 1;

  { !! this doesn't seem to work as expected, expected 1 dot, 2 spaces !!     }

  PenStyle     : DWORD     = PS_COSMETIC or PS_USERSTYLE;
  StyleCount   : DWORD     = high(PenPattern);
  StylePattern : PDWORD    = @PenPattern[low(PenPattern)];

  { this gives 1 dot, 1 space.                                                }

  //PenStyle     : DWORD     = PS_COSMETIC or PS_ALTERNATE;
  //StyleCount   : DWORD     = 0;
  //StylePattern : PDWORD    = nil;

  Pen          : HPEN      = 0;

var
  ps          : TPAINTSTRUCT;
  ClientRect  : TRECT;

begin
  WndProc := 0;

  case Msg of
    WM_CREATE:
    begin
      PenBrush.lbColor := RGB(255, 0, 0);

      Pen := ExtCreatePen(PenStyle,
                          PenWidth,
                          PenBrush,
                          StyleCount,
                          StylePattern);
      exit;
    end;

    WM_PAINT:
    begin
      BeginPaint(Wnd, ps);
        GetClientRect(Wnd, ClientRect);

        SelectObject(ps.hdc, Pen);  { use the pen we created    }

        MoveToEx(ps.hdc, 0, ClientRect.Bottom div 2, nil);
        LineTo(ps.hdc, ClientRect.Right, ClientRect.Bottom div 2);
      EndPaint(Wnd, ps);

      exit;
    end;

    WM_CLOSE: PostMessage(Wnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);

    WM_DESTROY:
       begin
         if Pen <> 0 then DeleteObject(Pen);

         PostQuitMessage(0);

         exit;
       end; { WM_DESTROY }
  end; { case msg }

  WndProc := DefWindowProc (Wnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
end;

{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function InitAppClass: WordBool;
  { registers the application's window classes                                }
var
  cls : TWndClassEx;

begin
  cls.cbSize          := sizeof(TWndClassEx);           { must be initialized }

  if not GetClassInfoEx (hInstance, AppName, cls) then
  begin
    with cls do
    begin
      { cbSize has already been initialized as required above                 }

      style           := CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT;
      lpfnWndProc     := @WndProc;                    { window class handler  }
      cbClsExtra      := 0;
      cbWndExtra      := 0;
      hInstance       := system.hInstance;
      hIcon           := LoadIcon (hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
      hCursor         := LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
      hbrBackground   := COLOR_WINDOW + 1;
      lpszMenuName    := nil;
      lpszClassName   := AppName;                     { Window Class name     }
      hIconSm         := 0;
    end; { with }

    InitAppClass := WordBool(RegisterClassEx(cls));
  end
  else InitAppClass := TRUE;
end;

{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function WinMain : integer;
  { application entry point                                                   }
var
  Wnd : hWnd;
  Msg : TMsg;

begin
  if not InitAppClass then Halt (255);  { register application's class        }

  { Create the main application window                                        }

  Wnd := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                        AppName,                { class name                  }
                        AppName,                { window caption text         }
                        ws_Overlapped       or  { window style                }
                        ws_SysMenu          or
                        ws_MinimizeBox      or
                        ws_ClipSiblings     or
                        ws_ClipChildren     or  { don't affect children       }
                        ws_visible,             { make showwindow unnecessary }
                        20,                     { x pos on screen             }
                        20,                     { y pos on screen             }
                        400,                    { window width                }
                        200,                    { window height               }
                        0,                      { parent window handle        }
                        0,                      { menu handle 0 = use class   }
                        hInstance,              { instance handle             }
                        nil);                   { parameter sent to WM_CREATE }

  if Wnd = 0 then Halt;                         { could not create the window }

  while GetMessage (Msg, 0, 0, 0) do            { wait for message            }
  begin
    TranslateMessage (Msg);                     { key conversions             }
    DispatchMessage  (Msg);                     { send to window procedure    }
  end;

  WinMain := Msg.wParam;                        { terminate with return code  }
end;

begin
  WinMain;
end.
```

Comment: With GDI+: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-drawing-a-custom-dashed-line-use

Comment: @ Michael, thank you.  That is helpful.  Am I correct in thinking there is no solution using GDI ?  (I ask because I'm much more adept with GDI than GDI+ but, this might be a good reason to increase my knowledge.)  I don't mean to impose on you but, if you could show a snippet of code written in Delphi to do it, it would be a pleasure to mark that as the answer.

Comment: Actually you should switch to Direct2D. Both D2D and GDI+ are C++ based, more easy to manage and offer lots of useful things like antialiasing, translations etc. I don't think a solution exists for GDI. Also, put the delphi tag so someone that knows how would help.

Comment: @ Michael, I welcome that suggestion but, I am a complete ignorant in D2D.  I would really need an example for D2D.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35890/Direct2D-Hardware-Acceleration-in-Windows-7-Plotti one of my older articles about it.

Comment: @ Michael, thank you!  I can use that. :)  That should be enough for me to figure it out and learn something too.  Perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It took me a little time to implement the GDI custom dashed line, just as you described it.

In GDI, custom dashed lines are drawn in dashes, as mentioned in MSDN.

> If `dwPenStyle` is `PS_COSMETIC` and `PS_USERSTYLE`, the entries in the `lpStyle` array specify lengths of **dashes** and spaces in style units. A style unit is defined by the device where the pen is used to draw a line.
>
> If `dwPenStyle` is `PS_GEOMETRIC` and `PS_USERSTYLE`, the entries in the
>   `lpStyle` array specify lengths of **dashes** and spaces in logical units.

This functionality can be implemented in GDI +, as mentioned at the beginning by @Michael Chourdakis

Comment: @ Strive, thank you.  I was afraid that ExtCreatePen would only output dashes except in the _one_ case when PS_ALTERNATE is specified which does not give a chance to specify the spacing between dots.  I'll use GDI+.  I guess the time has come to become more knowledgeable with it and, as Michael mentioned D2D.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur Of course, the more you learn, the faster you progress, come on.

Comment: @ Strive, just in case, if you happen to have some simple Delphi code to draw such a line. That would be great.  If not, no problem, I'm sure I will figure it out but, having code that already does it correctly would definitely save me some time.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur Ok, I will help you pay attention and give you an answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to control the length of the dashes and spaces in a line, call the [ExtCreatePen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-extcreatepen) function to create a `PS_USERSTYLE` pen. This allows you to specify an array of up to 16 entries, each one specifying the length of a dash or a gap.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion.  I intend to accept your answer even though I am not able to get 1 dot followed by 2 spaces out of it.  I would be grateful if you had a look at the test program I posted and let me know if there is a mistake somewhere that causes a dash to be drawn instead of a dot.  I should mention that, after careful reading of the MSDN description, I am under the impression that a custom pen will always use dashes instead of dot.